# Trying to use redux with react

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, react-redux, fetch-api

So, I have a react app where I'm using multiple apis to get some data and I'm trying to start using redux in it. I already watched some redux tutorials but I'm still a little bit confused when I begin to think how to convert this react app to react-redux. Like how to convert something like this, where I'm using (this.setState) to redux. I know I have to use react-thunk to start fetching this api in the actions but I'm still confused. here is my code.

```
componentDidMount(){

  let url = ``;
  let url2 = ``;



    fetch(url,{
      method: 'GET'
    })
    .then((response)=> response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      const newItems = responseJson.items.map(i => {
        return{
          name: i.name
        };
      })
      const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
        items: newItems
      });

      console.log(newState);
      this.setState(newState);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
    fetch(url2,{
      method: 'GET'
    })
    .then((response)=> response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      const newItems = responseJson.item.map(i => {
        return{
          img: i.img.url
        };
      })
      const newarr = [...this.state.items, ...newItems];
      var resObj = newarr.reduce(function(res, obj) {
          for(var key in obj) {
              if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                  res[key] = obj[key];
              }
          }
          return res;
      }, {});

      const newState = {
        items: [resObj]
      }

      this.setState(newState);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });


}
```

Comment: What’s your exact issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://redux.js.org/faq/codestructure

Redux can be intimidating at first

The first thing you want to know don't use `this.setState`, at least not yet.

Here is the structure of redux with react

[image]

To keep it simple, all you need to understand is Dispatchers, Connect, Action and Reducers.

- Action: An action is a plain object that represents an intention to change the state. Actions are the only way to get data into the store. Any data, whether from UI events, network callbacks, or other sources such as WebSockets needs to eventually be dispatched as actions.https://redux.js.org/glossary#action
- Reducer: A reducer (also called a reducing function) is a function that accepts an accumulation and a value and returns a new accumulation. They are used to reduce a collection of values down to a single value. https://redux.js.org/glossary#reducer
- Connect: Connect is basically a way of your components receiving the data from the global state. An output from the state that inputs into your components.
- Dispatch: Dispatchers are functions that you use to input to touch the state.

Anywhere you want to use `this.setState`, you want to use a dispatch which talks to the action (actions describe and define the dispatch function. This is where `redux-thunk` will come into play with the fetch function). After the dispatch calls the action and action pulls the data from the server, reducers clean up the data and send it back to the global store state where with the connect command, react picks up.